# I want to manage errors I receive in django forms on html page the way I want

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

[image]have created a from with some validations. I want to display an error on HTML properly, eg. If I am receiving an error for the password field I want to display it in front of that field. I am sharing my code as well as a screenshot of the page after I receive an error on the form. In short I want to manage the form errors on HTML the way I want.

forms.py

```
class UsersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(8),])
    password_1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,label='Confirm Password')    
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','date_of_birth')
        labels = {
            'date_of_birth': ('D.O.B'),
        }
        widgets = {
            'date_of_birth': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        }
```

views.py

```
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UsersForm(request.POST)
        u = User.objects.get(username=request.user.get_username())
        if request.POST.get('password') != request.POST.get('password_1'):
            messages.error(request,'password mismatch, try again')
            return render(request,'login.html',{'form':form})         
        elif form.is_valid():
            cUser = Users.objects.create(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                password=make_password(form.cleaned_data['password']),
                date_of_birth=form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth'],
                created_by= u,)
            cUser.save()
        else:
            return render(request,'login.html',{'form':form})            
    form = UsersForm()
    context = {"form":form}
    return render(request,'login.html',context)
```

login.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <pre><center>
            <h1>User Creation Form</h1>
            <form action = '' method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}    
            <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}              
            </table>  
            <input type="submit" name="register">               
            <h3>  
                {% for message in messages %}
                {{ message }}
                {% endfor %}
            </h3>
        </form>   
        </center></pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is fully documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) (nb: scroll down a bit for the part about rendering errors).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is fully documented with examples.

Comment: First look if [adding a css class to the error divs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#styling-required-or-erroneous-form-rows) is sufficient (you can then style divs with these classes as you want). If not, then don't use `{{form.as_table}}` but more granular output, by individually writing {{ form.field }}, {{ form.field.label }} and {{form.field.errors}} for each field (either looping through the fields or doing it for each field if they need special treatment).

Comment: Also, you definitly want to move the password validation to your form - this is documented too (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)